# How to calculate specific values - Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have 5 plain texts in XML and I want to do the following:

8 000 000 000 / text1 * text2 / text3 * text4 - text5

Here's what I have:

```
    btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    text1 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text2 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    text3 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    text4 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    text5 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    text = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textB = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String a,b,c,d,e,f;
            Integer vis;
            a = text1.getText().toString();
            b = text2.getText().toString();
            c = text3.getText().toString();
            d = text4.getText().toString();
            e = text5.getText().toString();
            f = textB.getText().toString();
            vis =  Integer.parseInt(a)+Integer.parseInt(b)+Integer.parseInt(f); //And so on..
            text.setText(vis.toString());

        }});
}
```

My question: How can I calculate these values? I tried to test this out, but the app shut itself down. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.valueOf()` returns a String. You cannot divide or perform any non-additive mathematical operators on Strings, which explains your error.

```
The operator / is undefined for the argument type.
```

In other words, you're trying to do something like `"3" * "3"` where you actually want `3 * 3`.

You're probably looking for [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a String and outputs an integer value. For example:

```
String s = "1234";
int i = Integer.ParseInt(s);
System.out.println(i * 3);
```

Comment: The text1,2,3,4 and 5 are not always the same - their value are depending on what number is put in.. Should I use the integer, then?

Comment: Yes, you need to convert all of their text field values to integers. By default they are Strings. That's fine, but you need them to be in a numeric format if you want to perform mathematical operations with them. You could create 5 int variables, like for example: `int textInteger1 = Integer.parseInt(edit1.getText().toString());`

Comment: So..How do I finally calculate these integer? I have made 5 integer variables but dont excatly know how to calculate them.

Comment: Edit your question above to include your new code, then comment here and I will help you further by editting my answer above.

Comment: When the app shuts down, do you get any errors or warning messages in your IDE? I don't know much about android dev so I'm not sure how it works. The portion of the code about getting Strings and converting them to integers seems fine to me.

Comment: I found out the problem is when the high number is put-in. While working with small numbers it works fine.

Comment: You can use the method `Long.parseLong()` to deal with larger numbers. For extremely large values, you can use the Java `BigInteger` class. Construct a BigInteger object with the String value in your text field, then perform the manipulations with BigInteger objects, then output a String. It's a tedious process but it will work for virtually all length Strings.

Comment: Where do I put the Long.parseLong() method?

Comment: Just replace the `Integer.parseInt(..)` method with `Long.parseLong(..)` identically. Then change your `vis` variable to a `Long` value.

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly, tho I would like to work with 0.XX values...What method do I input in case of working with 0.X numbers?

Comment: In this case, your options are to use the `Double.parseDouble` method (and change `vis` to a Double, obviously). This will allow you to parse pretty large decimal value strings. If you want unlimited precision, you can use the corresponding `BigDecimal` class. You simply construct a `BigDecimal` object from each String, then manipulate the objects themselves, and convert it back to a String with the `toString()` method to write to your result field.